# How does a flatMap on a double-generic data-structure looks like?

Tags: swift, functional-programming, monads, flatmap

I have the following (simple) data structure:

```
struct Work<Input, Output> {
    let work: Input -> Output
}
```

This type represents work which can take an `Input` and turns in into a desired `Output`. I am trying to see whether this data structure conforms to some functional concepts like a functor or a monad.

**Functor**

```
extension Work {
    func map<MoreOutput>(transform: Output -> MoreOutput) -> Work<Input, MoreOutput> {
        return Work<Input, MoreOutput> {
            return transform(self.work($0))
        }
    }
}
```

That seems to be correct as far as I am aware. I am able to write a map function which can turn `Work<Input, Output>` into `Work<Input, MoreOutput>`

**Monad**

I have trouble thinking of the definition for a `flatMap` (or `fold`) function for `Work`. The only thing I can come up with is the following:

```
extension Work {
    func flatMap<MoreOutput>(transform: Work<Output, MoreOutput>) -> Work<Input, MoreOutput> {
        return Work<Input, MoreOutput> { input in
            return transform.work(self.work(input))
        }
    }
}
```

If you look up the `flatMap` definition for an `Array` in swift it looks like this (simplified):

```
func flatMap(transform: (Element) -> T?) -> [T]
```

This is a function where its argument is a function which transforms an `Element` into `T` and results an `Array`. I cannot think of a way to abstract this to the `Work` type.

From another functional book I found a general definition for flatMap as follows (on an object `F` holding type `A`):

```
func flatMap<B>(f: A -> F<B>) -> F<B>
```

which is a different definition of `flatMap` than `Array` seems to implement.

Can someone explain this difference to me? And is it even possible to define a 'correct' `flatMap` function on `Work`? Or does `Work` not satisfy the properties to be a Monad?

** **Edit**

Thanks phg for so much useful info. I've tried to do the Profunctor definition:

Making `Work` a `Profunctor`:

```
extension Work {
    func diMap<A, B>(fa: A -> Input, fb: Output -> B) -> Work<A, B> {
        return Work<A, B> { arg in
            let input = fa(arg)
            let output = self.work(input)
            return fb(output)
        }
    }
}
```

Does that look right to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
func flatMap<B>(f: A -> F<B>) -> F<B>
```

is what you want `flatMap` to look like; it's the monad's usual ["bind" operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29#Formal_definition). Specialized for functions over the second argument, you get the so-called [Reader monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178889/reader-monad-purpose):

```
extension Work {
    func flatMap<MoreOutput>(g: Output -> Work<Input, MoreOutput>) -> Work<Input, MoreOutput> {
        // (Reader f) >>= g = Reader $ \x -> runReader (g (f x)) x
        return Work<Input, MoreOutput> {
            g(self.work($0)).work($0)
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I actually don't speak Swift, this code was just guessing -- hence the included Haskell original. Feel free to edit in a corrected version.

---

Now to the other definition:

```
func flatMap(transform: (Element) -> T?) -> [T]
```

I suppose `T?` means something like "optional `T`" or "nullable `T`". This is not what we usually understand as a monadic function, but it is related. Indeed, there has been [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407356/multiple-flatmap-methods-for-a-single-monad/16408309#16408309) about such "generalized flatMaps". The answer is, that if two monads are compatible, i.e., there exists a *monad morphism* `F<A> -> G<A>` preserving monadic structure, it makes sense to define

```
func wrappedFlatMap<B>(f: A -> F<B>) -> G<B>
```

which is probably exactly what is happening here for the "option type" and the list type, where the morphism is logically just

```
Just x ~> [x]
Nothing ~> []
```

Comment: Oh, and while you're at it, you could make `Work` a [profunctor](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-4.1/profunctors-5.1.2/Data-Profunctor.html)!

Comment: Great, that's a lot of useful info! Edited my answer to add my first try of a profunctor on `Work`.